# Problem with dpkg -p

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I'm trying to have informations about kernels installed with `dpkg -s` but the return is weird (and in french), but not seems to work:

```
$ dpkg -p linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
dpkg-query: le paquet « linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic » n'est pas disponible
Utilisez dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) pour examiner les fichiers
archives, et dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) pour afficher leur
contenu.
```

It says that the package is missing (not available)... :(

However, no problem with the option `-s`:

```
$ dpkg -s linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
Package: linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 44140
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux
Version: 3.16.0-28.38
Provides: fuse-module, ivtv-modules, kvm-api-4, linux-image, linux-image-3.0, redhat-cluster-modules
Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6), module-init-tools (>= 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3)
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.10.24)
Recommends: grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | grub-efi-ia32 | grub | lilo (>= 19.1)
Suggests: fdutils, linux-doc-3.16.0 | linux-source-3.16.0, linux-tools, linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic
Conflicts: hotplug (<< 0.0.20040105-1)
Description: Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
 This package contains the Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on
 64 bit x86 SMP.
 .
 Also includes the corresponding System.map file, the modules built by the
 packager, and scripts that try to ensure that the system is not left in an
 unbootable state after an update.
 .
 Supports Generic processors.
 .
 Geared toward desktop and server systems.
 .
 You likely do not want to install this package directly. Instead, install
 the linux-generic meta-package, which will ensure that upgrades work
 correctly, and that supporting packages are also installed.
```

What is the problem with the option `-p` ?
I precise that this option `-p` works with another package (firefox, or other)
I'm on Kubuntu 14.10 (x64)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `dpkg -p` is an alias for `dpkg-query -p` which is defined as:

> Display details about package-name, as found in  /var/lib/dpkg/available.
>    Users of APT-based frontends
>   should use apt-cache show package-name instead

and `dpkg -s` is an alias for `dpkg-query -s` which is defined as:

> Report status of specified package.

So, as far as I can tell, you've probably got that specific kernel installed via the `linux-generic` metapackage. That's why `-s` works. It would be assumed, however, that `linux-generic` should be present in /var/lib/dpkg/available and not `linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic`, which would be why `-d` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've found the reason.. the file `available` is not updated in 14.10 anymore. The new file is called `status` in the same repertory. I've seen this because the last modification of the file `available` is 26/10/2014, the date of the migration to 14.10... So, `dpkg -p` hasn't seen the package !!

Comment: @Guillaume, So did you find a solution for this. If so, could you  write an answer.